# How do I get the pixel data from a video file loaded locally through the HTML5 Files API?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to load a local video file and get its pixel data:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var video = document.createElement("video");
  video.src = fr.result;
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  });
});
fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```

A similar snippet works for image files, but for videos I get this error at the `ctx.getImageData(..)` call:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong but canvas will not allow `ctx.getImageData` if you have drawn an image whose source is not in the same domain as the webpage itself. As noted by your error message, this restriction is for very good security reasons.  The fix is to put your video in the same domain as your web page.

Comment: But why does it work with images then? Shouldn't the same security restrictions apply to them?

Comment: There are several possible "stoppers" here: loadedmetadata is no guarantee for having actual video data (you need canplay for that). readAsDataURL; data-uri's have length restrictions in some browsers. You would need to use blob/ArrayBuffer at least, but it would kill buffering and the video would need to be loaded entirely into memory first. getImageData uses video size. You should set canvas size first to be sure. play() must be called inside a canplay event handler. I don't think you in any case will be able to use video buffering with a blob object...